# Splitting audio to 2 headsets

Tags: headphones

I'm looking to do this for 30 machines, and preferably i want to do it without amp box. The space is not too big so no oversize gaming headphones..
Question is should i use Usb or aux headsets? Im a bit torn here,
Usb headsets that are within my budget usually have oversized diameter, only aux headsets hace ideal diameter, but if i use aux I've tried y splitters before some of my clients have reduced volume... is there anyway to split with aux without reduced volume?

Answer (score 1):

You need analogue headphones with a suitable headphone amplifier. You cannot do this any other way.

Comment: I have specific budget limit for each client, and amp box is just too overkill. I'm just looking for ways to prevent reduced volume. It's not gonna be used for anything audio intensive..

Comment: The only thing you can try is to purchase lower-impedance headphones or to simply split the signal and supply a mono feed. Each output is stereo, so you could supply a splitter that sends Left to client 1 and Right to client 2

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, it's 2 headsets per client. So each client must be able to split audio into 2 headsets. (thats why amp box is overkill) Is there any guideline on how many impedance values i'd need?

Comment: lowest possible impedance. 4 ohms if possible.

Comment: Hmm..Looks like most headphones in my country is 32 ohms.. what about this, 2 analog headsets + 2 cheap 3.5 to usb converters, would there be a volume reduction?

Comment: No, but your problem will be routing the audio at the driver level so that it splits.

Comment: If getting additional hardware to do the job is out of the question, could you add some information on the computers you are using? Operating system, any additional hardware in addition to the usual USB and audio ports?